# C++ filter algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, range

I am trying to create filter algorithm for my range library. I found 4 different approaches, how this could be done, with different pros & cons.

**a) Allocate new range, to which filtered range is copied**

pros: original range is not mutated, size of new range is automatically adjusted to have same size as number of filtered elements

cons: I am not sure, if algorithms should be allowed to allocate memory

**b) Pass another range as parameter to algorithm & c) Override original range**

pros: relatively straight forward implementation

cons: in b), need for iterator validity checking in range I am copying filtered elements into,

in c) what will happen with elements past-the-end of original range?

**d) Create adaptor over original range, which will act as filtered range**

pros: original range is not mutated, can be applied lazily

cons: need for filtered range adaptor class

Which one of these possible approaches do you think is best? Should I make it possible to use multiple of these versions? Do you think that algorithms should be allowed to allocate memory (perhaps some simple temporary data structure)?

Comment: You forgot one: pass a range and an iterator which is a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which automatically grows the destination container.

Comment: I think this falls under b) if you pass something like back_inserter range, however how can you enforce that passed range behave like back_inserter?

Comment: I took your comment about iterator validity checking to mean you were passing a range to an already populated container.

Comment: I will vote vote *d* even if it requires additional works